# 'as' parameter in the route::controller - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Within my application i was working with the following route:

```
Route::get('router', ['as' => 'router.index', 'uses' => 'RouterController@index']);
```

For the purposes of using `Datatables`, the route has to be defined differently.

```
Route::controller('router', 'RouterController', [
    'dataTablesData' => 'datatables.data',
    'index' => 'router',
    ]);
```

This causes my application to crash due to the missing `'as' => 'router.index'`. Where should I place the `as` parameter in a `Route::controller`?

Comment: the array key `as` is not required, so it should not crash your application. Could you show us the error? You are probably using `router.index` somewhere in your application while it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The error which I am getting is: `Call to a member function getName() on null` which comes from my sidebar menu. This code uses the `isRouteIn`, this this causes the error.

Comment: Also I have defined: `route('router.index')` in the code where the error occures..

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::controller(
    'router',
    'RouterController',
    array(
        'index'     => 'router.index',
    )
);
```

try something like that?

Comment: I need the `dataTablesData` parameter which is missing and adding this makes the code exactly like mine.